# In what cases will 'histeq' of MATLAB report a warning as 'Converting NaN inputs to 0'?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I performed 'histeq' over a batch of images and I got a number of repeated warnings as 'Converting NaN inputs to 0'. I have no idea how this occurred.
   MATLAB's info is:

```
警告: Converting NaN inputs to 0. 
> In imhist (line 76)
  In histeq>computeCumulativeHistogram (line 181)
  In histeq (line 138)
```

Does anyone have knowledge about this? Thanks!

The lines of MATLAB code having generated these are:

```
% gray-scaled image
img = fun_image_color(img,'GRAY');

% histogram equalization
img = histeq( img );
```

where the function 'fun_image_color' is defined as:

```
%% image color
% This function converts the input image to a specific color format.
function output = fun_image_color(img,imgColor)
if (nargin~=2), fun_messages('incorrect input parameters','error'); end

% color space
switch (imgColor)
    % gray-scale image -GRAY-
    case 'GRAY'
        % convert RGB image to gray-scale image
        if (size(img,3)==3), img = rgb2gray(img);end
    % RGB image
    case 'RGB'
        % convert gray-scale image to RGB 
        if (size(img,3)==1),
            tmp = cat(3,img,img);
            img = cat(3,tmp,img);
        end
    % HSV image
    case 'HSV'
        % check
        if (size(img,3)==1),fun_messages('the input image is not RGB','error'); end
        % HSV image
        img = rgb2hsv(img);
    otherwise
        fun_messages('incorrect color mode','error');
end

% normalization
img = fun_image_normalize(img);

% output
output = img;
end
```

where the function 'fun_image_normalize' is defined as:

```
%% Image normalization
% This function normalizes the input image between [0,1].
function output = fun_image_normalize(img)
if (nargin~=1), fun_messages('incorrect input parameters','error'); end

% normalize
img = double(img);
img = img - min(img(:));
img = img./max(img(:));

% output
output = img;
end
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve]

Comment: @SardarUsama Hi, I posted the code related to these warnings, and in this process I noticed the warnings could possibly be caused by dividing-by-zero operations in 'fun_image_normalize'.